# complex analysis-roots of constant polynomial function

Tags: complex-analysis

**True or False**: There exists a value for $w\in \mathbb{C}$ such that the equation $z^{100}+z +1 = w$ has no solution with $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

*My answer*

$False$-By fundamental theorem of algebra,Every non-constant polynomial has a root in $\mathbb{C}$.

what would be the root(s) of $z^{100}+z +1 = w$  for above answer if it is true?

Comment: Well, then **false** is the correct answer precisely by the FTA...

Comment: There is no closed-form expression for the roots of $z^{100}+z+1=w$.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I have edited the question, so is it possible to find a root to support my answer.

Comment: @ Gerry Myerson: Could it be found by any Mathematic software.

Comment: @Ittay Weiss: What would be the roots for above if we wish to find it?

Comment: @Avinesh, I can't see anything different: the answer still is **false** since the *polynomial* $\,z^{100}+z+1-w$ has one root (in fact, all $\,100\,$ of them) in $\,\Bbb C\,$ *no matter* what $\,w\in\Bbb C\,$ is.

Comment: @ DonAntonio, thanks.

Comment: Avinesh, when I write "there is no closed-form expression for the roots," I mean, **"there is no closed-form expression for the roots."** Software can find you a root to 10 or 100 or 1000000 decimal places, but it can't find you a closed-form solution.

Comment: @ DonAntonio: Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is known that there does not exist a closed form over radicals for the roots of arbitrary polynomials; there does exist closed forms for all polynomials of degree less than 5 and there does exist closed forms for some polynomials with higher degrees, but not all of them.

Essentially this means that the only method to find the roots of polynomials is to approximate them. Here is an interesting way to "solve" polynomials:

Start with: $$x^2-x-1=0.$$

By quadratic formula one of the roots is $$\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}.$$

But what if I didn't know the quadratic formula (or in general, what if I didn't have a formula), well solve for $x$ instead:

$$x=1+\frac{1}{x}.$$

Since $x=1+\frac{1}{x}$ we must have

$$x=1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}.$$

Since $x=1+\frac{1}{x}$ we must also have

$$x=1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{x}}}.$$

To infinity we arrive at:

$$x=1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\ddots}}}}}$$

and the more interesting consequence is that

$$1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\ddots}}}}}=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}. $$

They must be the same since they are both a positive root of a polynomial that only has one positive root. At the beginning we stated that not all polynomials are solvable by radicals; another way of making that statement is to say that not all "continued approximation expressions" will simplify to a nice radical expression. However, the creepy "continued approximation expressions" can always be found.

One could approach the polynomial above in the same way and find one of the roots to be:

$$z=\sqrt[100]{w-1-\sqrt[100]{w-1-\sqrt[100]{w-1-\sqrt[100]{w-1-\sqrt[100]{\cdots}}}}}$$

In this case the expression might not converge unless we pick an appropriate starting point, however when the expression above does converge it must be a root of the polynomial since it satisfies the equation.

If the above answer is upsetting, then the more upsetting consequence is that every method provided to you to find a root will reduce to some "approximation formula" like the one shown above, unless (of course) the above expression "magically" reduces over radicals and we just didn't see how it does.

Besides very tedious inefficient Galois Theory, there is no known simple method of determining when an expression will reduce over radicals. :-(